# H2 select LIMIT and OFFSET with random()

Tags: sql, select, random, h2, offset

In h2 dbms I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE sometable
( ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  somevalue INTEGER)
```

And some data

```
INSERT INTO sometable(somevalue) 
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

When I `SELECT somevalue FROM sometable LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2` **it works**. **Why** if I want to select random row the 
`SELECT somevalue FROM sometable LIMIT 1 OFFSET (RANDOM()*4)` **doesn't work**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
create table test(
  id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
  name varchar(255));

insert into test 
select x, 'Hello ' || x from system_range(50, 1200);

select * from test t, system_range(1, 100) range
where t.id = x * (select max(id)-min(id) from test) / 100 + 
(select min(id) from test);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316500/selecting-random-rows-from-a-big-table-in-h2-database)